# Is there any way to make a dhtmlx-grid from multiple tables fully editable?

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-tables, dhtmlx

I have a dhtmlx-grid created from multiple tables. And I am able to edit the main table but not the joined ones.

The dhtmlx guides are rather vague on creating a grid from multiple tables and making it fully editable.
I followed the steps here:
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/connector__php__complex_queries.html#complexqueries
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/connector__php__basis.html#loadingfromdatabase

and tried to create a connection, but failed.
I'm using their php-connector and the code that I tried is as follows:

```
$jpnx_regs = new GridConnector($conn,'MySQL');                    // connector initialization
$jpnx_regs->sql->attach("Update","
UPDATE wp_japanextion_attendance_data
LEFT JOIN wp_buyer_employee
    ON wp_buyer_employee.ID = wp_japanextion_attendance_data.ID_employee
LEFT JOIN wp_buyer_company
    ON wp_buyer_company.ID = wp_buyer_employee.ID_company
SET
    reg_user='{reg_user}',
    reservation_date='{reservation_date}',
    reservation_hour='{reservation_hour}',
    copy_company_name='{copy_company_name}',
    copy_company_TEL='{copy_company_TEL}',
    copy_name='{copy_name}',
    copy_mobile_TEL='{copy_mobile_TEL}',
    copy_email='{copy_email}',
    rec_creation_date='{rec_creation_date}',
    iploc='{iploc}',
    trackvia_inserted='{trackvia_inserted}'
WHERE id='{id}'
");

$jpnx_regs->render_complex_sql("
SELECT 
*,  wp_japanextion_attendance_data.ID AS jpnx_ID,
    wp_buyer_employee.ID AS employee_ID,
    wp_buyer_company.ID AS buyer_ID,
FROM 
wp_japanextion_attendance_data
LEFT JOIN wp_buyer_employee
    ON wp_buyer_employee.ID = wp_japanextion_attendance_data.ID_employee
LEFT JOIN wp_buyer_company
    ON wp_buyer_company.ID = wp_buyer_employee.ID_company
    WHERE
reservation_date LIKE '%November%' OR
reservation_date LIKE '%December%' OR
reservation_date LIKE '%January%'

    ", "jpnx_ID","
    reg_user,reservation_date,reservation_hour,company_name,company_TEL,name,mobile_TEL,email,rec_creation_date,iploc,trackvia_inserted,ID
");
```

↑　Just as their guide says. I first initialize the grid like this:

```
$jpnx_regs = new GridConnector($conn,'MySQL');
```

Then I attach the update action:

```
$jpnx_regs->sql->attach("Update"," ... sql code here
```

Then I render the grid with the render_complex_sql.

```
$jpnx_regs->render_complex_sql("
```

BTW, just in case, here down below is my working code for my grid from multiple tables but I can only update the main table:

```
$jpnx_regs = new GridConnector($conn,'MySQL');
if ($jpnx_regs->is_select_mode())
    $jpnx_regs->render_sql("
SELECT 
*,  wp_japanextion_attendance_data.ID AS jpnx_ID,
    wp_buyer_employee.ID AS employee_ID,
    wp_buyer_company.ID AS buyer_ID,
FROM 
wp_japanextion_attendance_data
LEFT JOIN wp_buyer_employee
    ON wp_buyer_employee.ID = wp_japanextion_attendance_data.ID_employee
LEFT JOIN wp_buyer_company
    ON wp_buyer_company.ID = wp_buyer_employee.ID_company
    ", "jpnx_ID","reg_user,reservation_date,reservation_hour,company_name,company_TEL,name,mobile_TEL,email,rec_creation_date,iploc,trackvia_inserted,ID
");
else //code for other operations - i.e. update/insert/delete
    $jpnx_regs->render_table("wp_japanextion_attendance_data","id","
    reg_user,reservation_date,reservation_hour,copy_company_name,copy_company_TEL,copy_name,copy_mobile_TEL,copy_email,rec_creation_date,iploc,trackvia_inserted");
```

Comment: You can try to enable logs, it will show was custom SQL code executed or not.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I tried that but I think logs don't get saved because wordpress doesn't give the permission for this... Do you know any workaround?

Comment: As far as I know, you must have write access for php user in the same folder where active script file resides ( in case of wordpress it will be the root folder of a site, most probably )